# How to chage the page suffix?

Tags: views

My page is starting from 0,and I want to start with1.
As follows:
[image]

Can implemented in Drupal?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Sort of.

The **?page=X** query parameter in views pages is the offset from the SQL results (if you have the views admin section displaying generated SQL you can see this by the `OFFSET X` clause).

Hence, if you adjust your **Pager options** such that the **Offset** (normally 0) is set to opposite (e.g. -5) of the number in the **Items per Page** (e.g. 5) it will produce the effect of **/my-views-page?page=1** containing the first results of your query.

However, it will also produce the side effect of the first offset page (i.e. **/my-views-page** and **/my-views-page?page=0**) of having no results. You could probably mitigate this through some URL rewriting, but it's a bit of work for something that has very little value (how many people browse the web thinking about numbered results vs. index offsetting?).